# How to use weighted data in linear modeling?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, weighted-regression, weighted

I have data from studies where each study has the means for that sub sample and the sample size is n, so the n is a frequency. There is one categorical predictor. The dependent variable is a % (the % issue has a separate question).

I used n/sum(n) for the weights and made weighted histograms and density plots as well as some linear models (iirc, some of the functions want probablities for weights).

Am i correct in using this weight for histograms and densities?

I see these questions where many different types of "weights" are used:

- [uses n^(3/4) and n](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7513/how-to-use-weights-in-function-lm-in-r)

  [uses 1/n and 1/n^2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408439/weighted-least-squares-r)

  [uses n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315867/r-lm-result-differs-when-using-weights-argument-and-when-using-manually-rew)

  [uses 1/n and 1/sqrt(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260017/how-to-set-a-weighted-least-squares-in-r-for-heteroscedastic-data) - this is trying to deal with
  heteroscedastic data

These different weights are confusing.

My data do not seem to be normally distributed and has a factor that indicates that the variances within each group are quite different.

I can sorta see using the 1/sqrt(n) to deal with heteroscedasticity, but given that my n is a frequency, it seems like we are throwing information away.

So is using n/sum(n) for the weights a reasonable thing to do with linear models?

Do I need to use this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268689/weighted-regression-in-r) (which uses n) to get the correct p-value?